# EAGLE: Change shape of Repour All Polygon

Tags: pcb, eaglecad

As you can see from the attached picture, I used some polygon area on the top side.

Anyway, the surface has some empty zone close to pad that I would like to fill with copper.

Do you know how to do that?

Thank you.[image]

Answer (score 1):

> Anyway, the surface has some empty zone close to pad that I would like
>   to fill with copper.

That may not be sensible because they are called thermal reliefs and allow the component to be properly soldered because the copper mass doesn't take too much heat away from the solder joint and therefore doesn't necessitate excessive heat given to the actual component.

[image]

You can always loop a regular copper connection across those "spare areas". Or just setup the thermal spokes to be bigger.

Answer (score 1):

Are you talking about the gap above the pad labeled "A/N$22"?

Try reducing the "width" of your polygon. This parameter controls the width of the aperture used to fill in the polygon interior, and a smaller width allows it to "flow into" tighter gaps.

However, too small a width will require many more Gerber commands to paint the polygon, making your Gerber files sizes grow enormously.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you "should" do this, but in order to actually do it you need to modify your DRC settings:

Type `drc` and then open the "Supply" tab:

[image]

(Fusion shown, but it's the same in Eagle)

Reduce the "Thermal Isolation" value to something that makes you happier. Then ripup your polygon (`ripup @;`) and regenerate (`ratsnest`). This setting will apply to all polygons in your design.

You can also turn thermals off for a particular polygon. Ripup the polygon (`ripup @;`) and then right click the border and select Properties. Uncheck the "Thermals" box:

[image]

**Setting a zero value or removing thermals will cause the pad to disappear!** A pad, after all, is just an isolated area of copper with a soldermask around it. Think very carefully about what this does to your design before removing it.

**As other answers have said though** this will reduce the ability for you to solder to that pad. You could end up with a cold joint or just no ability to heat it up to melt the solder. You may have to heat the entire board (or a large area around the pad) to be able to solder to it.